# Count cells in a row where value is greater than zero

Tags: powerquery

I'm looking to add a column to my PowerQuery data which will count how many of 5 cells in the row are greater than zero. Example data below with end result:

I could do this with lots of If statements but I need to be able to expand my number of columns in the future.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it. Add a column with:

```
List.Count(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_),{0}))
```

e.g.:
[image]